# To find a light weight android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Is there any light weight android emulator i can download from android studio?

Comment: Do you have a real device?

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider using Genymotion?
https://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can download Memuplay from: http://www.memuplay.com/ or Bluestacks from: https://www.bluestacks.com/ as emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's other emulators you can use such as genymotion, but if your problem is a slow network, you might have to wait a while for your download to complete. If you have an Android Smartphone I suggest you use it instead of the emulator. You just have to enable developer options.

There's some steps on how to setup your device for development [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device)